# iOS AppIntent with Siri - pass parameters in initial request

Tags: ios16, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts, appintents

I wanted to create a shortcut so my users can ask Siri to perform a certain task without having to open the app.

I checked out AppIntents but it seems like they can only perform static tasks like "***Add a book***" and then Siri will ask questions until it has every parameter that is required. Is there any way to already pass the parameters in the initial request like "***Add a book called Atomic Habbits by James Clear***"?

If not with AppIntents maybe with SiriKit somehow? It seems like, you can create shortcuts that do exactly that but not with Siri or am I missing something?